# R.java not generated after ADT update

Tags: java, android, build, r.java-file

I update my android tools and also my ADT. I cleaned my project and build it again. However after this action my /gen folder is empty.

I have made sure that none of my resource contains errors and also made sure that there is no import.R in my activity. I tried cleaning and rebuilding other projects as well with same error. I created a new android project and even the new project had and empty /gen folder.

**Solved:
After the update you need to restart the SDK manager and download android build tools. After i clean my projects everything is fine again. Thank you guys.**

Comment: Restart your eclipse!

Comment: try clean and build your project, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585964/class-not-found-error-after-updating-adt-and-android-sdk-tools-to-latest-ver-22 try this workaround

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127

Comment: if you are getting error to any resource or resource file then ADT wont create R.java file...first of all you need to resolve the error in resource file then R.java will be created

Comment: @SpeedAmphetamine follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16608570/1278196)

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I had the same problem.
That's what I did:

> **Upgrade Android Development Tools to v.22**

How?

**Tab Help -> Install new SW using this site: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse**

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing the correct android SDK location, and do you have the necessary platforms/api level that you are referencing in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try moving project folders to a different location, e.g. to your documents or another drive?

The errors with the build path can be fixed by clicking Android Tools->Fix Project Properties

**EDIT :**

1) Make sure you don't have any other errors other than the R-related errors. Right-click your project folder in Eclipse, Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties.
do this

2) Check to make sure you have the correct R imported. Sometimes the default Android.R can be imported.

3) Check for errors in your layout XML files.

Answer (score 0):

check in your sdk manager whether the android platform tools is installed , check whether the api you are targetting is installed and also in eclipse File-properties-builders check if everthing is selected. if all this is fine then if you have not restated your system after update then restart it.