# R.java missing after updating ADT to 22.0.1

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, r.java-file, eclipse-adt

> I know this problem has been discussed in "[Eclipse giving error, missing R.java file after recent update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update)" and "[R.java not generated after ADT update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707313/r-java-not-generated-after-adt-update)" but I still can't make it work.

My R.java file is not generated and I've searched here for answers but none of the answers have worked.
Everything worked just fine before I updated my ADT, so the code should be ok.
This is what I've tried:

- I don't have any "import android.R".
- In "Project"-tab -> "Build Automatically" is checked.
- I've cleaned my project and restarted eclipse several times.
- I've downloaded Android SDK Tools (22.0.1), Android SDK
  Platform-tools (Rev.17) and Android SKD Build-tools (Rev. 17).
- I've started a new "Android Sample Project" and a "Hello World" but
  the problem persists which means that there is no problem with my
  *.xml file.
- I've tried rightclicking on my project -> "Android Tools" -> "Fix Project properties".
- I've gone into "properties" of my project -> "Java Build Path" -> "Order and Export" where everything is checked and in this order: "src", "gen", "Android Private Libraries", "Android Dependencies", "Android 4.2.2", and two endpoint libraries (I'm working with App Engine).
- I've updated eclipse in "Help"-tab -> "Check for updates" and "no updates were is found" (I'm running Eclipse Juno SR2).
- I've installed new software in "Help"-tab -> "Install new software" from "http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" and "http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2".
- In "project.properties" target=android-17 and in "manifest" android:targetSdkVersion="17".

What should I do?
Please help me out here !

Comment: Hope you have checked that ADT and Android SDK are of the same version.

Answer (score 1):

Check on Java Compliance level to be set at 1.6

*Window*-*Preferences*-*Java Compiler*

Select on **Compiler compliance level: 1.6**

Also check on the problem window to see if your layouts (or other area) are showing an error and that is preventing the compiler to build the file.

Check on Problem window Alt+Shift+Q,X

Post resolution as it might help others.