# ClassNotFoundException after changing extension from Activity to BaseGameActivity

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception, google-play-services

I am trying to integrate `Android Google Play Services` from the [Android docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init).  I got all the steps working and it compiles with no errors.  At runtime on my splash screen, I get the below error.

```
05-30 21:08:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(7137): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-153
05-30 21:08:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(7137): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite.MainMenu
05-30 21:08:36.115: E/AndroidRuntime(7137):     at matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite.SplashScreen$IntentLauncher.run(SplashScreen.java:46)
```

Below is the code to "SplashScreen.java:46".

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainMenu.class);  //Line 46
startActivity(intent);
```

I just changed the opening line in my `MainMenu` from this:

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {
```

to this:

```
public class MainMenu extends BaseGameActivity {
```

And now I am getting the ClassNotFoundException.  Why is this error popping up?  The `MainMenu` class is definitely there.  More code can be provided upon request.

Android Manifest

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.2.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_blue_bg"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".About"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Categories"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Question"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Quiz"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".QuestionView"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Results"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Highscores"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".DatabaseHelper"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".ComingSoon"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MainMenu"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MyApplication"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".BibleStudy"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you add *BaseGameActivity* to your manifest?

Comment: Can you add your manifest.xml?

Comment: If you are using eclipse. Just try project -> clean and build

Comment: @Nambari and @autobot_101, `BaseGameActivity` is not a class.  Instead of extending `Activity` I use `BaseGameActivity`.  So I do not think I need to add that to my manifest.  Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ManuelPires - I edited in my manifest to my opening post.

Comment: @Ironhide I had already tried that but I did it again just now for safe measure.  Error still exists at runtime.

Comment: try changing 
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainMenu.class);  

to 
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, matt.lyons.bibletrivia.lite.MainMenu.class);

After that remove the import of MainMenu from you SplashScreen class. let us know what happens

Comment: I tried what you said @Ironhide and received the same LogCat output at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<activity android:name=".MainMenu" />` inside `application` tag in Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new activity in:

```
File->New->Other->Android Activity->Blanc Activity
```

Then in `Hierarchical Parent` select `BaseGameActivity`...

After that copy the code of your MainActivity to the activity you just created...

I believe that way you'll not have the error.

Comment: I am not sure what I am going to accomplish doing this.  I am going to end up extending `BaseGameActivity` in 3 or 4 classes total.  Will I have to do this for all of them?

Comment: Your class was initialized in the class loader as extends of Activity... when you change it to BaseGameActivity, the class definition searched is as extends of Activity... Have you tried? Just because if this solution doesn't work I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.

The answer to this question solved it for me.
[Class not found error after updating ADT and Android sdk tools to latest ver 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585964/class-not-found-error-after-updating-adt-and-android-sdk-tools-to-latest-ver-22)

Comment: Please try to avoid link-only answers. Instead, outline the core idea of the solution. Links might out date quickly and so information is lost.