# Changed package name in android project, now getting noclassdeffounderror

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

I had a android project that was working perfectly. It had three activities: MainActivity, CorrectAnswerActivity, and UserFailed. I am using the Google Play Services api on CorrectAnswerActivity and UserFailed so these are extending BaseGameUtil.

This was all fine until I thought it would be a good idea to change my package name (because I changed my games name). So now when you click on a button on MainActivity, which will take you to either Failed or Correct, I'm getting noclassdeffounderror as if it can't find the CorrectAnswerActivity or UserFailed.

I updated my Manifest with the new package name, and every other place it was mentioned.

```
08-20 21:45:29.765: E/AndroidRuntime(5549): 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.blackcrowndev.numbers.CorrectAnswerActivity
08-20 21:45:29.765: E/AndroidRuntime(5549):      at com.blackcrowndev.numbers.MainActivity.onClickGuess(MainActivity.java:254)
```

I feel as if it has something to do with

```
public class CorrectAnswerActivity extends BaseGameActivity
implements View.OnClickListener {
```

But I didn't change anything within the libraries.

Thanks for the help guys. I'm really new to Java and Android dev, so please let me know if I need to provide any more information. I will leave you with my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.blackcrowndev.numbers"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Password" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.blackcrowndev.numbers.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.blackcrowndev.numbers.CorrectAnswerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_correct_answer"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.blackcrowndev.numbers.UserFailed"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_failed"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.blackcrowndev.numbers.HowToPlay"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_how_to_play"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild your whole project after the name change? And can you confirm what package `CorrectAnswerActivity` is in?

Comment: I did clean the entire project. 
All my activities are in com.blackcrowndev.numbers

Comment: Remove all the jar files added under  java build path.Clean the Project.Now add the jars back in java build path.Clean again.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project and then Go to properties -> javabuild path  -> order export select required and clean your project.

Comment: This did not seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are in trouble with ADT bug.

Check - 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55304

And there are some similar question and answer in StackOverflow

[ClassNotFoundException after changing extension from Activity to BaseGameActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898105/classnotfoundexception-after-changing-extension-from-activity-to-basegameactivit)

Know workaround is "Go to Properties->Order and export on the app project and check 'Android Private Libraries'" for all library projects. (In your case, google play services library should be set as 'Android Private Libraries'.

Answer (score 0):

Change the package name in the manifest file, corresponding to each class file, if anything not renamed!!