# Android QR generator

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing, noclassdeffounderror

For weeks I have been trying to use the ZXING library to create an app that generates and displays a simple QR code containing text. I have read just about every other question on this topic and can't get it to work.

I think I am close, at the moment I have the core.jar included as a reference for my project, and I also have the android library from the zxing folder as a referenced library.

Here is my code:

```
String uniqueID="hi";
    BarcodeFormat barcodeFormat = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
    int width0 = 500;
    int height0 = 500;
    QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
    try
    {
        EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object> hint = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
        hint.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(uniqueID, barcodeFormat, width0, height0, hint);
        int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
        int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            int offset = y * width;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {

                pixels[offset + x] = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? android.graphics.Color.BLACK : android.graphics.Color.WHITE;
            }
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.qrCode);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This code doesn't have any errors. When I run the app and click the button which runs this code, I get the following logcat output:

```
06-19 15:33:34.493: W/dalvikvm(1340): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1076 (QR_CODE) in Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat;
06-19 15:33:34.493: D/dalvikvm(1340): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0002
06-19 15:33:34.493: D/dalvikvm(1340): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x114f at 0x0a in Lcom/example/qrgen/MainActivity;.genQR
06-19 15:33:34.493: I/dalvikvm(1340): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x043c at 0x14 in Lcom/example/qrgen/MainActivity;.genQR
06-19 15:33:34.963: D/libEGL(1340): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
06-19 15:33:34.993: D/libEGL(1340): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
06-19 15:33:34.998: D/libEGL(1340): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
06-19 15:33:35.003: D/(1340): Device driver API match
06-19 15:33:35.003: D/(1340): Device driver API version: 10
06-19 15:33:35.003: D/(1340): User space API version: 10 
06-19 15:33:35.003: D/(1340): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
06-19 15:33:35.073: D/OpenGLRenderer(1340): Enabling debug mode 0
06-19 15:33:38.883: D/AndroidRuntime(1340): Shutting down VM
06-19 15:33:38.883: W/dalvikvm(1340): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x420312a0)
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3691)
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3686)
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     ... 11 more
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at com.example.qrgen.MainActivity.genQR(MainActivity.java:36)
06-19 15:33:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     ... 14 more
```

It appears that the problem lies with com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat, but I checked my referenced libraries and that class does exist. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you updated your ADT version recently? Because the latest version (ADT 22) causes dependencies (such as ZXing in your case) to crash with `NoClassDefFoundError`... which would, in this case, have absolutely no relation with your code.

The most common solution is [already on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585964/class-not-found-error-after-updating-adt-and-android-sdk-tools-to-latest-ver-22), check if it does the trick!