# Android .R not generating - checked all common causes

Tags: java, android, eclipse

After getting a new computer and setting up eclipse again, no projects are generating the .R file. The SDK is on revision 22 which I noticed some people had issues with, but setting the Private Libraries checkbox did not resolve this.

The .R isn't generating for existing projects nor brand new empty android projects. The SDK levels between the build configurations and the manifest match.

An entire uninstall of the SDK, and redownloading the Android version of eclipse and SDK didn't work as well. Could it be something with the versions of Java installed on the machine? Or is there some other common cause of the R not generating I missed after searching?

Comment: Anything in the console?

Comment: It seems a common issue. Check this link maybe it helps: http://blog.burnayev.com/2009/11/android-developer-tip-regenerating.html

Comment: @Varun - Nothing but the generic 'R file could not be found'.
-Freerider - Nothing out of the ordinary in res, created another test project from scratch, no .R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your SDK Tools from the SDK manager and ADT in eclipse, this was fixed in the latest update (22.0.1)

Also, after you update your SDK, close and reopen the SDK and check for updates again (in case you don't see 22.0.1)

Take a look here for some similar issues [Class not found error after updating ADT and Android sdk tools to latest ver 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585964/class-not-found-error-after-updating-adt-and-android-sdk-tools-to-latest-ver-22)

Comment: I think I checked the SDK manager yesterday, not sure if 22.0.1. Was present, but it was marked as installed with no available updates. Will check again though and reply back.

Comment: yeah, 22.0.1 is definitely what you want. make sure to check eclipse adt plugin as well.

Comment: Confirmed 22.0.1 is installed in SDK manager as well as ADT plugin

Comment: I think we got unlucky and something with the SDK/ADT package had issues when we originally downloaded. Completely wiped out anything android related, re-downloaded it, and it worked. We later noticed the "bad" Eclipse didn't even have the ADT options in the menu available.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error as yours.

**note:**
The SDK directory architecture of 22.0.1 version is different from before.
there is not platform-tools directory and some command file move to other directory.
but,eclipse and ADT plugin does not update according with SDK

so, linking related bin to platform-tools directory will work.

above meet my error.