# ClassNotFoundException on android blank activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, classloader, classnotfoundexception

I am having a problem with Android Studio (1.3 dev channel). I created the default blank activity from the menu (File->New->New project, and then API 16 as minimum SDK, Blank Activity, default settings). I wanted to test, with such a simple setup, if I can load the class called `MainActivity` from my package. To this end, I simply added the following to the `OnCreate` method:

```
    ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

    try {
        Class stringCla = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("java/lang/String");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Class civeCLass = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("com/alecive/yarpdroid/MainActivity");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

At runtime, the first try (i.e. with `java/lang/String`) is successful, wheras it fails with the second one, i.e. `com.alecive`yarpdroid`. This is the stackTrace:

```
06-19 09:12:35.646  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
06-19 09:12:35.646  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 408: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
06-19 09:12:35.646  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
06-19 09:12:35.646  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 430: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/dalvikvm﹕ dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'com/alecive/yarpdroid/MainActivity'
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com/alecive/yarpdroid/MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at com.alecive.yarpdroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
06-19 09:12:35.676  32405-32405/com.alecive.yarpdroid W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

For completeness, here is my `MainActivity.java` (please tell me if you need anything else, but I did not touch any other file apart from this one):

```
package com.alecive.yarpdroid;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        try {
            Class stringCla = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("java/lang/String");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Class civeCLass = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("com/alecive/yarpdroid/MainActivity");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alecive.yarpdroid" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.alecive.yarpdroid.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: As a follow up, this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585964/class-not-found-error-after-updating-adt-and-android-sdk-tools-to-latest-ver-22 did not help me because I am not using `Eclipse` but `android studio` instead. If you can guide me toward a similar workaround, maybe that one could be my solution!

Comment: try to change the class loader `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` with this one `this.getClass().getClassLoader()`

Comment: 1) Your traceback shows you've *already* loaded com.alecive.yarpdroid.MainActivity".  Clearly that's not a problem.  2) What makes you think "com/alecive" is necessarily in your current directory (or current CLASSPATH)?  Please follow the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803326/this-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-nullpointerexception).  3) Try this: `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();`

Comment: Why `com/alecive/yarpdroid/MainActivity` and not `com.alecive.yarpdroid.MainActivity`?

Comment: @immibis your suggestion does not work either.

Comment: @GabriellaAngelova your solution works! Please add it as an answer in order for me to accept it as the proper one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тry to change the class loader `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` with this one `this.getClass().getClassLoader()`