# Google Map does not load on emulator with Jelly Bean 4.3

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am building an app that uses android Google api v2. But whenever I try to launch, it crashes. I have all the libraries added to my project. However, after adding Google play services library, it shows a cross sign when I reopen the project's properties (under Library section). I don't think this is causing my app to crash but I couldn't find the reason behind this error. I re-downloaded Google play services as well. Please help me fix this crashing!

LogCat shows:

"Caused by:android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment:Make sure class name exists, is public and has an empty constructorthat is public"

......

"Caused by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16583188/2045570

Comment: Thanx for the references!